# How to Print iterations of a Sorting function in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to print the iterations of the function as it goes through the loop, the text after the code is what the output should look like, this is my first time asking i dont know if i am doing it right.
    //Abdulfattah Abutaha's Code please use as reference only.
    #include 
    #include  
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;

void SelectionSort(vector<int>& A)

{
    int temp,pos_min;
    int n=A.size();
    for (int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        pos_min = i;
        for (int j=i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[pos_min])
            {
                pos_min=j;
            }
        }
        if (pos_min != i)
        {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pos_min];
            A[pos_min] = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    num="";
    nums.clear();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the next element (Enter 'q'to stop):"<<endl;

    while(num!="q")
    {
        cin>>num;
        if(num == "q")
        {
            continue;
        }
        cout<<"Enter the next element (Enter 'q'to stop):"<<endl;
        numbers=stoi(num);
        nums.push_back(numbers);
    }
    SelectionSort(nums);
    cout<<"Sequence: ";
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<nums[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
===Selection Sort====================================
Min -78,swap with 90:-78 -8 34 90 34 235 9 -12 653 
Min -12,swap with -8:-78 -12 34 90 34 235 9 -8 653 
Min -8,swap with 34:-78 -12 -8 90 34 235 9 34 653 
Min 9,swap with 90:-78 -12 -8 9 34 235 90 34 653 
Min 34,swap with 34:-78 -12 -8 9 34 235 90 34 653 
Min 34,swap with 235:-78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 235 653 
Min 90,swap with 90:-78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 235 653 
Min 235,swap with 235:-78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 235 653 
Sequence: -78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 235 653
```

Comment: You have variables in `main()` that aren't defined. Please provide us with and MCVE - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this (add the three lines I've marked.) Note that I haven't tried this.

```
void SelectionSort(vector<int>& A)
{
    cout << "===Selection Sort====================================" << endl; // <--
    int temp,pos_min;
    int n=A.size();
    for (int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        pos_min = i;
        for (int j=i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[pos_min])
            {
                pos_min=j;
            }
        }
        cout << "Min " << A[pos_min] << ", swap with " << A[i] << ":"; // <--
        if (pos_min != i)
        {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pos_min];
            A[pos_min] = temp;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) cout << " " << A[k]; cout << endl; // <--
    }
}
```

Comment: It complied and it gave me a runtime library. Expression:vector subscript out of range

Comment: Fixed the runtime error. The loop termination condition was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I made quite a few edits to the original code. I tried to annotate all of them with a comment. The code works as requested.

Updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void selectionSort(vector<int>& A) // Changed the function name to start with lower case here and in main
{
    int temp,pos_min;
    int n=A.size();
    cout << "===Selection Sort====================================" << endl; // Added print statements
    for (int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        pos_min = i;
        for (int j=i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[pos_min])
            {
                pos_min=j;
            }
        }
        cout << "Min " << A[pos_min] << ", swap with " << A[i] << ":"; // Added print statements
        if (pos_min != i)
        {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pos_min];
            A[pos_min] = temp;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) // Changed this from k <= n to k < n
        {
            cout << " " << A[k]; // Added print statements
        }
        cout << endl; // Added print statements
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int SENTINAL = 9999; // Used a numerical sentinal to exit user entry loop
    int num(0); // Declared data type of num and initialized
    vector<int> nums; // Declared nums as a vector of ints

    nums.clear(); // Redundant as nums was initialized as an empty vector but doesn't really hurt

    cout<<"Enter the next element (Enter '9999' to stop):"<<endl; // Changed the sentinal stop value
    cin>>num;

    while(num!=SENTINAL) // Used sentinal value here
    {
        nums.push_back(num);
        cout<<"Enter the next element (Enter '9999' to stop):"<<endl;
        cin>>num;
    }

    selectionSort(nums); // Calls selectionSort function on nums vector

    cout<<"Sequence: "; // Prints the sorted sequence at the end
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<nums[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output from this code:

```
===Selection Sort====================================
Min -78, swap with 34: -78 9 34 90 -8 235 -12 653 34
Min -12, swap with 9: -78 -12 34 90 -8 235 9 653 34
Min -8, swap with 34: -78 -12 -8 90 34 235 9 653 34
Min 9, swap with 90: -78 -12 -8 9 34 235 90 653 34
Min 34, swap with 34: -78 -12 -8 9 34 235 90 653 34
Min 34, swap with 235: -78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 653 235
Min 90, swap with 90: -78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 653 235
Min 235, swap with 653: -78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 235 653
Sequence: -78 -12 -8 9 34 34 90 235 653
```